# Can I ground one sub panel to another sub panel in this situation?

Tags: electrical

I would like to retro fit a ground conductor from one sub-panel to another where both are fed from the main.

I purchased remote property in Alaska. It has a 200 amp Main panel and 2 subpanels. In the Main Panel the ground and neutral bar are bonded.

From the Main panel there is a 100amp breaker feeding 100amp subpanel A approx. 180 ft. away. The feeders to subpanel A are a 4 conductor cable 2-2-2-4 RUD alum. #4 being the ground. Ground and neutral are NOT bonded. Subpanel A feeds 2 R.V. parking spaces, shower house, bunk house, well and Some outlets. works great.

From the Main panel there is another 100 Amp breaker feeding 100amp subpanel B approx. 220 ft. away. The feeders to subpanel B are a 3 conductor cable 2-2-2 RUD alum. The ground and neutral bars are NOT bonded. There is No Equipment Ground conductor from the Main Panel  to sub panel B. Sub panel B services a 2 bedroom 1000 sq.ft. very nice cabin fully furnished.

All 3 panels have ground rods attached.

I'm fairly sure after I need a #4 grounding conductor from panel B to get back to the bonded ground bar in the main panel for ground faults.

Can I retro fit a #4 conductor from the ground bar in Sub panel B to Sub panel A, as subpanel A has an equipment ground in place going back to the main panel, completing bonding and the distance is much less, 75 ft.

[image]

---

<sub>From comments provided in an "answer":</sub>

- Yes Sub panel B Does have equipment grounding.
- Yes I'm just missing the equipment ground feed from Sub panel B to the main panel.
- No the feeds are direct burial, no metal conduit.
- Was thinking I could tap off Subpanel A's equipment ground as its closer to Subpanel B.

Comment: Does your wiring in the cabin (subpanel B) have equipment ground conductor wiring, and you are just missing ground connection from subpanel B back to main panel? Is your feed from main panel to subpanel B inside metal conduit that might be used as the EGC between the two?

Answer (score 2):

That's fine.

However, #2 aluminum is not 100A wire.  It's 90A wire.  You'll need to downsize those breakers.

[image]

(People think it is 100A wire because an exception in code allows service wires to a dwelling to be sized 83% of service ampacity, so 83A to a 100A service.  That doesn't help you any, your service is 200A).

Can you power two 50A RV stands from a 90A feeder? *Yes, actually!* Table 551.73.  Based on the near nil chance both RVs will be maxed out at the same time.

Comment: And this is why the recommendation: USE CONDUIT!